# Selecting columns from dataframe based on the name of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes, 
df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['CTA15', 'CTA16', 'AC007', 'AC007', 'AC007'], 
'AA_ID': [22, 22, 2, 2, 2], 
'BB_ID':[4, 5, 6, 8, 9], 
'CC_ID' : [2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
  'DD_RE': [4,7,8,9,0],
    'EE_RE':[5,8,9,9,10]})
```

and df_ID,

```
df_ID = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['CTA15', 'CTA16', 'CFV', 'SAP', 'SOS']})
```

and the other one is`df_RE`, both of these data frames has the column Name, so I need to merge it to data frame df, then I need to select the columns based on the last part of the data frame's name. That is, for example, if the data frame is `df_ID` then I need all columns ending with `"ID" + "Name"` for all matching rows from `Name` from data frame `df`, and if the data frame id `df_REL` then I need I all columns ends with `"RE" + "Name"` from df and I wanted to save it separately.
I know I could call inside the loop as,

```
for dfs in dataframes:

    ID=[col for col in df.columns if '_ID' in col]
    df_ID=pd.merge(df,df_ID,on='Name')
    df_ID=df_ID[ID]
```

But here the ID , has to change again when the data frames ends with RE and so on , I have a couple of file with different strings so any better solution would be great

So at the end I need for df_ID as having all the columns ending with ID

```
 df_ID = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['CTA15', 'CTA16'],
                        'AA_ID': [22, 22'],
                         'BB_ID':[4, 5],
                           'CC_ID' : [2, 2]})
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Using `pd.merge` gives the result you are expecting. Have you tried it?

Comment: Could you please check my edited question. I have tried But the main part of my question is selection columns based on file name .

Comment: You just want to keep those columns with `ID` in them?

Comment: If the data frame within the dfs is ending with _ID, another wise check the name in the data frame and select columns based on that. That is, for example, if the data frame is df_ID then I need all columns ending with "ID" + "Name" for all matching rows from Name from data frame df, and if the data frame is df_REL then I need I all columns ends with "RE" + "Name" from df. I think I need have a if loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your columns in `df` are `Name` and anything with a suffix such as the examples you have listed (e.g. `_ID`, `_RE`), then what you could do is parse through the column names to first extract all **unique** possible suffixes:

```
# since the suffixes follow a pattern of `_*`, then I can look for the `_` character
suffixes = list(set([col[-3:] for col in df.columns if '_' in col]))
```

Now, with the list of suffixes, you next want to create a dictionary of your existing dataframes, where the keys in the dictionary are suffixes, and the values are the dataframes with the suffix names (e.g. `df_ID`, `df_RE`):

```
dfs = {}
dfs['_ID'] = df_ID
dfs['_RE'] = df_RE
...  # and so forth
```

Now you can loop through your `suffixes` list to extract the appropriate columns with each suffix in the list and do the merges and column extractions:

```
for suffix in suffixes:
    cols = [col for col in df.columns if suffix in col]
    dfs[suffix] = pd.merge(df, dfs[suffix], on='Name')
    dfs[suffix] = dfs[suffix][cols]
```

Now you have your dictionary of suffixed dataframes. If you want your dataframes as separate variables instead of keeping them in your dictionary, you can now set them back as individual objects:

```
df_ID = dfs['_ID']
df_RE = dfs['_RE']
... # and so forth
```

#### Putting it all together in an example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['CTA15', 'CTA16', 'AC007', 'AC007', 'AC007'],
                   'AA_ID': [22, 22, 2, 2, 2],
                   'BB_ID': [4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
                   'CC_ID': [2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'DD_RE': [4, 7, 8, 9, 0],
                   'EE_RE': [5, 8, 9, 9, 10]})

# Get unique suffixes
suffixes = list(set([col[-3:] for col in df.columns if '_' in col]))

dfs = {}  # dataframes dictionary

df_ID = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['CTA15', 'CTA16', 'CFV', 'SAP', 'SOS']})
df_RE = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AC007']})

dfs['_ID'] = df_ID
dfs['_RE'] = df_RE

for suffix in suffixes:
    cols = [col for col in df.columns if suffix in col]
    dfs[suffix] = pd.merge(df, dfs[suffix], on='Name')
    dfs[suffix] = dfs[suffix][cols]

df_ID = dfs['_ID']
df_RE = dfs['_RE']

print(df_ID)
print(df_RE)
```

**Result:**

```
   AA_ID  BB_ID  CC_ID
0     22      4      2
1     22      5      2
   DD_RE  EE_RE
0      8      9
1      9      9
2      0     10
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and code. But as I mentioned in my question I need column "Name" also in df_ID and df_RE

Comment: gotcha. if you need to add 'Name' as well, then its just a simple edit to the existing code in the for loop. Change `dfs[suffix] = dfs[suffix][cols]` to `dfs[suffix] = dfs[suffix][cols + ['Name']]`

Answer (score 1):

You can first merge df with df_ID and then take the columns end with ID.

```
pd.merge(df,df_ID,on='Name')[[e for e in df.columns if e.endswith('ID') or e=='Name']]
Out[121]: 
   AA_ID  BB_ID  CC_ID   Name
0     22      4      2  CTA15
1     22      5      2  CTA16
```

Similarly, this can be done for the df_RE df as well.

```
pd.merge(df,df_RE,on='Name')[[e for e in df.columns if e.endswith('RE') or e=='Name']]
```